# Restrict Jacoco coverage calculcation on methods with cyclomatic complexity > 2

Tags: jacoco, cyclomatic-complexity, clover

Is there a way to tell Jacoco not to take into account the methods with very low cyclomatic complexity(CyC)(CyC<2) while calculating the coverage percentage?

NB:I think this is doable in Atlassian-clover either by filtering out the method with [CyC <= maxComplexity](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/clover-setup), or by defining a custom metric that ["multiplies the  coverage value by  CyC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648966/measure-unit-code-coverage-for-function-method-on-cyclomatic-complexity)

Comment: I opened https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/728 for that.