# Improving a JUnit Parameterized test beyond minimum requirements

Tags: java, junit

I made a JUnit parameterized test that does the job fine. I made some improvements to it by adding lots of test cases (success and failure) and features like names for parameters:

```
@Parameters(
        name = "{index}:tweakedParameter: {0}, parameter1: {1}, parameter2: {2}, parameter3: {3} ...")
```

Are there any other improvements I can make to get a better test functionally/ aesthetically/ anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I think mainly your unit test should strive to get 100% full coverage of your code. To gain it usually you can use tools , check [answer about coverage tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399514/how-to-check-code-coverage-with-tests-for-methods-with-specified-level-of-comple)